# Stop KendoUI from converting UTC to local time

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am using KendoUI charts and am feeding it timestamps in utc and when it does its conversion to a human readable date it converts it to the local browser time automatically. Not sure why its doing this and if there is a setting I can set to stop it from doing this. I have tried doing the below and it doesn't want to stop converting it to local time.

I just want it to create a human readable date from the timestamp I give it, and not convert it unless I tell it to.

```
categoryAxis: {
  categories: [],
  labels: {
    font: '12px Roboto',
    rotation: 'auto',
  },
  type: 'date',
  baseUnit: 'days',
  maxDivisions: 16,
  format: 'u' // also tried 'zzzz'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Kendo charts, but if it's API doesn't offer anything to solve your problem, you could format the date yourself, and present it to the chart as a string instead of a Date. I guess you'd have to set type: 'string' instead of type: 'date' as well.